# Rsync for syncing 4TB from SMB to USB Volume 'Hostnameproblem'

Tags: macos, filesystems, file-transfer, rsync, smb

I've got a problem with rsync (3.1.2.) on a MacOS 10.11.6, because I don't know how to enter the hostnames correctly. My approach was this:

```
$ sudo rsync -vaE --progress smb://company-nas/old_Projects/old_Projects_11 /Volumes/old_Projects_11
```

and what I get is:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname smb: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rsync does not support SMB itself. The URL you specified was most likely copied from some file management tool. It won’t work.

Instead, you have two options:

- If you *have to* use SMB, you have to mount it.
- If you have SSH access to the file server, you can use rsync’s native protocol (over SSH) to transfer the data.

#### SMB

Just browse to the share in Finder. As soon as it appears on the Desktop, it’s mounted at `/Volumes/<whatever>`. Probably something like `/Volumes/old_Projects/old_Projects_11`. This path can be used with `rsync`.

*On Linux*, you’d have to install the “cifs-utils” package (or something equivalent) and mount it manually:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=<username>,password=<password> //company-nas/share /mnt/my-mount-point
```

#### SSH

If you have SSH access to the file server and it has rsync available, you can use `rsync`’s own protocol, which may be much more efficient when you’ll have to resume the transfer at some point.

```
rsync -e ssh your-user@company-nas:/path/to/share /Volumes/old_Projects_11
```

You will then be prompted for *your-user*’s password and the process will start.

**Important:** Instead of the share name, you’ll need the full path to the shared folder.